# Java 8 Sum two object properties in one iteration

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<LedgerEntry> ledgerEntries` and I need to calculate the sums of creditAmount and debitAmount.

```
class LedgerEntry{
 private BigDecimal creditAmount;
 private BigDecimal debitAmount;

 //getters and setters
}
```

I have implemented this as,

```
BigDecimal creditTotal = ledgeredEntries.stream().map(p ->p.getCreditAmount()).
reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal debitTotal = ledgeredEntries.stream().map(p ->p.getDebitAmount()).
reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

//...
//Use creditTotal, debitTotal later
```

This looks like I'm iterating over the List twice. Is there a way to get this done in one go without having to steam the list twice?

Pre Java 8 version

```
BigDecimal creditTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
BigDecimal debitTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for(LedgerEntry entry : ledgerEntries){
  creditTotal = creditTotal.add(entry.getCreditAmount());
  debitTotal = debitTotal.add(entry.getDebitAmount());
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use streams? Your "Pre Java 8" version is also 100% valid Java 8 and (when fixed for the fact that it doesn't actually do anything because `BigDecimal`s are immutable) more readable and maintainable (and probabably more performant) than any stream solution which tries to calculate the two sums at once.

Comment: @KrazyKalle : Thanks. did the edit

Comment: @KrazyKalle. Yes. What do you think I meant with the sentence between parentheses (when fixed ... immutable)?

Comment: By the way, you can write `.filter(LedgerEntry::getCreditAmount)` to use method references for the lambdas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could reduce to a totals entry:

```
LedgerEntry totalsEntry = entries.stream().reduce(new LedgerEntry(), (te, e) -> {
    te.setCreditAmount(te.getCreditAmount().add(e.getCreditAmount()));
    te.setDebitAmount(te.getDebitAmount().add(e.getDebitAmount()));

    return te;
});
```

---

**Update**

In the comments it was correctly pointed out that `reduce()` should not modify the initial identifier value, and that `collect()` should be used for mutable reductions. Below is a version using `collect()` (using the same `BiConsumer` as both accumulator and combiner). It also addresses the issue of potential NPEs if the `creditAmount` and/or `debitAmount` values have not been set.

```
BiConsumer<LedgerEntry, LedgerEntry> ac = (e1, e2) -> {
    BigDecimal creditAmount = e1.getCreditAmount() != null ? e1.getCreditAmount() : BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal debitAmount = e1.getDebitAmount() != null ? e1.getDebitAmount() : BigDecimal.ZERO;

    e1.setCreditAmount(creditAmount.add(e2.getCreditAmount()));
    e1.setDebitAmount(debitAmount.add(e2.getDebitAmount()));
};

LedgerEntry totalsEntry = entries.stream().collect(LedgerEntry::new, ac, ac);
```

All of the sudden the pre-Java 8 version is starting to look mighty attractive.

Comment: Could `new LedgerEntry()` be replaced with `LedgerEntry::new` for the sake of readability?

Comment: @CKing No. It's the initial value, not a method reference.

Comment: Noted. I assumed `reduce` would have an overloaded form that takes a functional interface such as a `Supplier` but guess there is no such thing.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for the answer. However, I see one potential issue with this solution. It will throw a NullPointerException since new LedgerEntry() has the creditAmount and debitAmount set to null by default. If I make the entity (LedgerEntry) to have BigDecimal.ZERO as the default value it will fix the problem, but that doesn't look good on the entity

Comment: @CKing that's because **this answer shows an invalid use of `reduce()`**: the first parameter is the `identity`, and the `BinaryOperator` is not supposed to modify it. It should instead return another object. It is collection operations that require to modify their input (and indeed they take a `Supplier` as parameter).

Comment: @DidierL Pardon my ignorance. You are right. I'll look into updating my answer.

Comment: @Krishan does `LedgerEntry` have a constructor that takes values for `creditAmount` and `debitAmount`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen : It does not. As you have correctly pointed, pre java 8 version seems attractive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your results into a `Pair` of some sort:

```
stream
        .parallel()
        .reduce(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO),
                    (entry, ledger) -> {
                        BigDecimal credit = BigDecimal.ZERO.add(entry.getKey()).add(ledger.getCreditAmount());
                        BigDecimal debit = BigDecimal.ZERO.add(entry.getValue()).add(ledger.getDebitAmount());
                        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(credit, debit);
                    }, (left, right) -> {
                        BigDecimal credit = BigDecimal.ZERO.add(left.getKey()).add(right.getKey());
                        BigDecimal debit = BigDecimal.ZERO.add(left.getValue()).add(right.getValue());
                        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(credit, debit);
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's only two values, you can use Collectors method [`teeing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) (JDK 12+)

From docs:

> Returns a Collector that is a composite of two downstream collectors. Every element passed to the resulting collector is processed by both downstream collectors, then their results are merged using the specified merge function into the final result.

```
LedgerEntry ledgerEntry = ledgeredEntries.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                            p -> p.getCreditAmount(), //you can replace with method reference
                            BigDecimal::add),
        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                            p -> p.getDebitAmount(),
                            BigDecimal::add),
        LedgerEntry::new)
    );
```